How does one make throat singing (VVM/kargyraa) sound more like natural chest voice?
I have lately been interested in "basso-profondos". Upon researching this topic online, I have stumbled upon a singer (Alexander Mayang) that has a high-baritone to tenor speaking voice, and yet can reach low notes (for example C2) with a lot of power and resonance in what sounds (to me) like simple chest voice.
Further looking into this, I found in one of his first videos that he (very briefly) mentions using VVM (vocal ventricular mode) that - to my understanding - is the mechanism used in kargyraa throat singing. However, traditional kargyraa (or at least what I've heard) does sound bass-y but has a very particular timbre that is quite different from (regular) chest voice.
How does he get such a clean and natural sounding "throat bass" ? is it just sheer practice/skill, or is there a subtle difference from conventional kargyraa in the way he uses it ?
Thanks in advance for any insight!
